# Nontrivial example of when monadic functors don't compose

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

It is well-known that the composite of monadic functors $U: C \to C'$ and $U': C' \to C''$ need not be monadic. One standard example is the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Cat} \to \mathrm{RefGph}$ from categories to reflexive graphs, followed by the functor $\mathrm{RefGph} \to \mathrm{Set}$ that takes a reflexive graph to its set of arrows.

Another example is by taking the full inclusion of torsionfree abelian groups in abelian groups, followed by the forgetful functor from abelian groups to sets. The first is monadic because it is a reflective subcategory inclusion. But the composite, the forgetful functor from torsionfree abelian groups to sets, is not monadic. Another example in this vein: the forgetful functor from commutative rings with no nonzero nilpotents to sets is not monadic.

For every example of this phenomenon I've seen so far, there is a uniform and very easy reason for why $U'U$ is not monadic. Let $F$ and $F'$ be the left adjoints to $U: C \to C'$ and $U': C' \to C''$, respectively. Then $U'F'$ and $(U'U)(FF')$ are both monads on $C''$, and there is a morphism of monads

$$U'\eta F': U'F' \to U'UFF'$$

where $\eta$ denotes the unit of $F \dashv U$. In every case I've seen, it happens that this monad morphism is an isomorphism. Consequence: if $U'U$ were in fact monadic, then $C$ and $C'$ would both be equivalent to the Eilenberg-Moore category of this same (up to iso) monad on $C''$, i.e., the comparison functor $U: C \to C'$ would have to be an equivalence. But it's manifestly not, for each of these examples.

Call this, that $U'\eta F'$ is an isomorphism but $U$ is not an equivalence, a "trivial" reason for why a composite of monadic functors need not be monadic. Can anyone give me a nontrivial example, where the composite $U'U$ isn't monadic but where $U'\eta F'$ is not an isomorphism?

Comment: I think you get a counterexample if you take categories over nonreflexive graphs over Set^2

Comment: Yes, I guess this does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about torsion-free abelian groups to X to sets, where X is (not presumed abelian) groups, or commutative monoids, or monoids in general.

It seems to me these all work as examples for the question as written (in each case, with the first monadic functor being a reflective subcategory inclusion), but I am hesitant to trust myself.

Comment: I think this works. You get isomorphic monads for this case iff $\eta F'$ is an isomorphism, i.e. iff free groups are in fact torsionfree abelian groups, which they are not.

Comment: More generally, for any non-monadic functor $G : A \rightarrow B$, there is at most one way to factor $G$ as a composition of two monadic functors which is "trivial" in the sense of this question (it would have to be the factorization through the Eilenberg-Moore category for the monad corresponding to the adjunction in which $G$ is the right adjoint). So any alternative factorization of this same $G$ as a composition of two monadic functors will serve as a non-"trivial" example.

Comment: Yes, of course. I wish I'd had the idea before; it's simple enough.

Comment: By the way, Sridhar: this question was instigated by a conversation still going on at the Category Theory Zulip, under the thread "distributive laws and monadic functors". A lot of interesting observations are being made. (I see that you're a member, but you might not have tuned in recently.)